# Dynamic Mapping for Nested Type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a dynamic mapping for objects like the following:

```
  {
    "product": {
        "productId": 99999,
        "manufacturerId": "A0001",
        "manufacturerCode": "A101LI",
        "name": "Test Product",
        "description": "Describe the product here.",
        "feature_details":{
            "category": "Category1",
            "brand": "Brand Name"
        },
        "feature_tpcerts":{
            "certifiedPass": true,
            "levelCertified": 2
        },
        "feature_characteristics":{
            "amount": 0.73,
            "location": 49464
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the `feature_*` properties to be a nested type, which I have defined in the mapping below with the nested_feature template and it is working as expected. However, I also want to have each property in the nested object of the `feature_*`property to be `multi_value` with an additional `facet` property defined. I have tried the second nested_template template, but without any success.

```
 {
    "product" : {
        "_timestamp" : {"enabled" : true, "store": "yes" },
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
              "nested_feature": {
                "match" : "feature_*",
                "mapping" : {
                  "type" : "nested",
                  "stored": "true"
                }
              }
            },
            {
                "nested_template": {
                    "match": "feature_*.*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "{name}": {
                                "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                "index": "analyzed"
                            },
                            "facet": {
                                "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        ],
        "properties" : {
            "productId" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"},
            "manufacturerId" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index" : "analyzed"},
            "manufacturer" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "manufacturerCode" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "yes"},
            "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes"},
            "description": {"type": "string", "index" : "analyzed"}
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the properties within the `feature_*` properties are created from another process and can be almost any name/value pair. Any suggestions on how to use a dynamic template to setup a property as nested as well as make each property within the nested object `multi_field` with an additional `facet` property?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just have to use `path_match` instead of `match` when the pattern refers to the whole field path, otherwise only its name (last part) is taken into account. Have a look at the [reference page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html) for the root object, which contains also some documentation related to dynamic templates.

You might also want to use `match_mapping_type` as you can't set `"index":"analyzed"` for numeric or boolean fields for instance. In that case you might want to do different things depending on the field type.

I noticed that your document contains the product root object, which you don't really need. I would remove it, as the type name is already product.

Also, I would avoid storing fields explicitly unless you really need to, as with elasticsearch you have the [`_source` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) stored by default, which is what you are going to need all the time.

The following mapping should work in your case (without the product root object in the documents):

```
{
      "product" : {
          "dynamic_templates": [
              {
                "nested_feature": {
                  "match" : "feature_*",
                  "mapping" : {
                    "type" : "nested"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                  "nested_template": {
                      "path_match": "feature_*.*",
                      "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type": "multi_field",
                          "fields": {
                              "{name}": {
                                  "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                  "index": "analyzed"
                              },
                              "facet": {
                                  "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }                
          ]
      }
  }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for the advice about matching on field type, storing fields/_source field and document structure. I am new to working with Elasticsearch and these tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PaigeCook you're welcome, great you're looking into elasticsearch, I'm sure you'll soon start answering questions too about it! ;)