# elasticsearch Not_analyzed and analyzed

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

Hello For certain requirement i have made all the index not_analyzed

```
{
"template": "*",
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "my_template": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                    "mapping": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
   }
```

But now as per our requirement i have to make certain field as analyzed . and keep rest of the field as not analyzed

My Data is of type :

```
{   "field1":"Value1",
       "field2":"Value2",
       "field3":"Value3",
"field4":"Value3",
"field5":"Value4",
"field6":"Value5",
"field7":"Value6",
"field8":"",
"field9":"ce-3sdfa773-7sdaf2-989e-5dasdsdf",
"field10":"12345678",
"field11":"ertyu12345ffd",
"field12":"A",
"field13":"Value7",
"field14":"Value8",
"field15":"Value9",
"field16":"Value10",
"field17":"Value11",
"field18":"Value12",
"field19":{
"field20":"Value13",
"field21":"Value14"
},
"field22":"Value15",
"field23":"ipaddr",
"field24":"datwithtime",
"field25":"Value6",
"field26":"0",
"field20":"0",
"field28":"0"
}
```

If i change my template as per recommendation to something like this

```
{
   "template": "*",
   "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "filed6": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }}},
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "my_template": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then i get error while i insert data stating

{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [field19]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [field20 ]]; ","status":400}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short you want to change the mapping of your index.

- If your index does not contain any data(which I suppose, is not the
  case), then you can simply delete the index and create it again with
  new mapping.
- If your index contains data, you will have to `reindex` it.

Steps for reindexing:

- Put all data from existing index to dummy index.
- Delete existing index. Generate new mapping.
- Transfer data from dummy index to newly created index.

You can also give a look to `elastic search alias` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html#index-aliases)

[This](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) link might also be useful.

If you want to use the same field as `analysed` and `not analysed` at the same time you have to use `multifield` using

```
"title": {
"type": "multi_field",
"fields": {
    "title": { "type": "string" },
    "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
 }
}
```

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/_multi_fields.html) is for your reference.

For defining `multifield` in `dynamic_templates` use:

```
{
"template": "*",
"mappings": {
"_default_": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "my_template": {
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                 "mapping": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                   "type":  "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
               }
              }
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) for more info on this.

Comment: Yes I have to change it but i want to keep all the fields except some not analyzed . Also i need dynamic mapping so that any new field in logs will be not_analyzed . But i am not sure how should i do it .. Because i might have new fields anytime so there is not fixed format to create mapping as analyzed or not_analyzed

Comment: Addition of new fields is not a problem. You can add fields with whatever mapping you want.Problem comes when you have to change the existing mapping.Do you have a requirement where you might have to change analysed to not_analysed or vice versa again and again?

Comment: We might have requirement of making more fields as analyzed and also keep it not_analyzed at same time

Comment: The multifield is what you need. By using multifield you you can keep  the same field as analysed and not analysed at the same time. Editing the answer.

Comment: Can you share a example with my current template what should i change to get a field name "sid" to be analyzed and not_analyzed as in my question i have pasted the template which i am usign

Comment: Thanks @richa.. I am trying all the suggestion and i have modified my question and the dilemma i am facing as of now because of nested document .. I get error   {"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [pro]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [st]];

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309131/dynamic-mapping-for-nested-type

Comment: Thanks for link ..Well i am not able to write mapping to be honest and feel i am missing  something while writing mapping

Comment: What mapping are you trying?

Comment: `{
   "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "uid": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                  }}},
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "my_template": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can either write `multiple templates` or have separate properties depending on your requirements. Both will work smoothly.

1) Multiple Templates

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_doctype": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "analyzed_values": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match": "title|summary",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "date_values": {
            "match_mapping_type": "date",
            "match": "*_date",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "exact_values": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here *title* and *summary* are `analyzed` by `keyword analyzer`. I have also added `date` field which is optional, it will map *create_date* etc as date. Last one will match anything and it will `not_analyzed` which will fulfill your requirements.

2) Add analyzed field as properties.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_doctype": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        },
        "summary": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "any_values": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here *title* and *summary* fields are `analyzed` while rest will be `not_analyzed`

You would have to reindex the data no matter which solution you take.

**EDIT 1** : After looking at your data and mapping, there is one slight problem in it. Your data contains `object` structure and you are mapping everything apart from *filed6* as `string` and *filed19* is an **Object** and not string and hence ES is throwing the error. The solution is to let ES decide which `datatype` the field is with `dynamic_type`. Change your mapping to this

```
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "filed6": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "my_template": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "{dynamic_type}", <--- this will decide if field is either object or string.
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: how is first different from second .. Can you please help me to get understanding of properties and when do we use properties .. Also I would appreciate if you can relate if i want to keep same field as not_analyzed and analyzed then how would i do it .. Using the above two examples you gave

Comment: I have edited my answer after looking at your data and template. It should work now. AFA your question regarding properties and templates, basically you use templates when you are not in control of fields going inside ES and you want some control or you have lot of fields with similar characteristic. You use properties when there are few fields with different types and you want to use custom analyzers for specific fields, etc.